# Delay the Threadgroup in jmeter test

Tags: jmeter

I have 4 thread groups in my test. I have requirement as below:

I want first 3 thread groups to work sequentially. Hence, I have checked the chekcbox "Run Thread groups consecutively". But, i want my fourth thread group to start 30 mins after the third thread group while the third thread group is still not complete. Can this be achieved on Jmeter. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you tick `Run Thread groups consecutively` box you won't be able to have more than 1 thread group running at any moment of time.

So you need to untick that box on test plan level and start all Thread Groups in parallel.

The fact that the thread group has started doesn't necessarily mean that it will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), you can delay the execution until the previous Thread Group is done.

For example you can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) for this purpose, in 1st thread group and put something into a [FIFO queue](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Functions) and then try to read the value using `jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor` in the 2nd Thread Group (add it to the first sampler). The 2nd Thread Group will start executing samplers only when the value will be available in the queue.

See [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan for example implementation

The same approach should be applied for thread groups 3 and 4, when 3rd thread group starts - put something to the FIFO queue so 4th thread group would be aware that the 3rd one has started, then you can "sleep" for 30 minutes using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler

Comment: This definitely helps. But, the problem in starting all threads in parallel is: the 1st and 2nd thread group are for setting up the environment without which the 3rd thread group will fail. Any suggestions for this? And, does setting a time in Flow COntrol Action mean a pause or stop before each thread or pause/delay for the thread group 4 to start.

Comment: I added a Flow Control Action with 30min pause to thread group 4 but, what i notice is that there is a delay of 30 mins to start the thread group 4 and then there is a delay of 30mins between every loop. Is there a way to just add delay to start the thread group and then continue without a pause between loops.

Comment: I used startup delay under Threadlifetime setting of the Thread Group and it seems to work.

Comment: You can put Flow Control Action sampler under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition: `${__groovy(vars.getIteration() == 1,)}`, this way it will be executed only during first iteration of the Thread Group

Comment: Yes. This works. Glad!